# apex:selectlist dropdown UI issue on dropdown the right border is not visible

Tags: visualforce

Below the drop down i have 1 more drop down and a button so i think on drop down the border is unable because of the overlap any help is appreciated.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="out0">
            <apex:outputText value="Select Product Category: " style="font-size: small; font-weight: bold;"/> <br/>
            <apex:selectList id="selectedValue" value="{!chosenProductCategory}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions id="selectedProduct" value="{!productCategory}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="selectedGroupValue"/>
            </apex:selectList> <br /><br/>
            <apex:outputText value="Select Product Group: " style="font-size: small; font-weight: bold;"/><br/>
            <apex:selectList id="selectedGroupValue" value="{!chosenFieldSet}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions id="selectedProductGroup" value="{!products}"/>
            </apex:selectList> <br /><br/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" onClick="validationAddButton();" action="{!searchProduct}" status="pageStatus" rerender="default, out, out2" style="width: 35px; margin-left: 3px; border-radius: 5px;" disabled="{!disableAddBtn}" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

[image: I have just strikethrough the picklist value.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved: The issue was due to salesforce standard css that was applying to drop-down. Now i am overwriting the css property of font-size and the drop down is displaying correctly.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="out0">
            <apex:outputText value="Select Product Category: " style="font-size: small; font-weight: bold;"/> <br/>
            <apex:selectList style="font-size:110%;" id="selectedValue" value="{!chosenProductCategory}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions id="selectedProduct" value="{!productCategory}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="selectedGroupValue"/>
            </apex:selectList> <br/><br/>
            <apex:outputText value="Select Product Group: " style="font-size: small; font-weight: bold;"/><br/>
            <apex:selectList style="font-size:110%;" id="selectedGroupValue" value="{!chosenFieldSet}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions id="selectedProductGroup" value="{!products}"/>
            </apex:selectList> <br/><br/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" onClick="validationAddButton();" action="{!searchProduct}" status="pageStatus" rerender="default, out, out2" style="width: 35px; margin-left: 3px; border-radius: 5px;" disabled="{!disableAddBtn}" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

[image]